# MYSQL: Troubleshooting a Simple Query that Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to pinpoint what I’m missing here and where I should be focusing my attention for resolution.  I have two tables with two columns each.   The vast majority but not all of Table1.symbol will be in Table2.symbol.

Table1 —symbol  —date

Table2 —symbol  —industry

What I was attempting to do was not working so I’m trying to troubleshoot and pinpoint where I’m losing the thread.  At this point I’m merely trying to build my queries from the bottom up, but I’m unable to get results that I would expect.

First, I ran a number of queries just to see what gets returned.  Using phpMyAdmin I get the following :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
  —> (38,290 total, Query took 0.0002 sec)

SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM Table1
  —> (2,067 total, Query took 0.0016 sec)

SELECT * FROM Table2
  —> (7,072 total, Query took 0.0002 sec)

SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM Table2
  -> (7,072 total, Query took 0.0011 sec)

SELECT * FROM Table1, Table 2
  —> (270,786,880, Query took 0.0002 sec)
```

Issue 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.symbol = Table2.symbol
  (192 Total, Query took 0.0002)
```

This only returns 192 and the result set that is returned only has records from S through Z (but not all)

Issue 2:

```
SELECT Table1.symbol, Table2.industry WHERE Table1.symbol = Table2.symbol
  —> (192 total, Query took 1.5174)
```

This returns 192 as well, but hangs for over a minute before the results are returned. As with Issue 1, this also is limited to S through Z (but not all).

Issue 3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.symbol, Table2.industry WHERE Table1.symbol = Table2.symbol
   --> (times out)
```

Any guidance on how I might trouble shoot and resolve this would be appreciated.

[EDIT Adding Context]
Database Schema:

TABLE1: Symbol: varchar(6), Date: date

TABLE2: Symbol: varchar(6), Industry: varchar(100)

Due to lack of reputation I can not inline images, and am limited to 2 links so I'll post a third in the comments, however...

Table1 (alltimehigh) Sorted by Date to show the most recent records

http://i60.tinypic.com/29yqxow.png

Table2 (symbolbase) with WHERE to verify if one of the most recent entries in Table1 exist

http://i57.tinypic.com/20pqxvm.png

Ultimately my aim is to achieve:

```
SELECT alltimehigh.symbol, count(alltimehigh.symbol) as total, symbolbase.industry FROM alltimehigh, symbolbase WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '20' DAY) <= Date AND alltimehigh.symbol = symbolbase.Symbol GROUP by alltimehigh.symbol ORDER BY count(alltimehigh.symbol) DESC
```

But for now I'd be content just figuring out why I can not get a match from Table1.symbol to Table2.symbol to return all symbols from Table1 that are in Table2 and return them along with the associated Table2.industry to that symbol.

Comment: Do you expect `Table2` to have a superset of the symbols in `Table1`? It sounds like there is only a 192 symbol overlap between them, and your implicit inner join (comma-separated FROM clause) is correctly returning the set which is common to both tables.

Comment: Post a sample of rows you would expect to match both tables if you can.  Things like trailing whitespace and casing (depending on the column collation) would prevent a  join condition from matching as well...

Comment: I can manually verify that there are records before S that both Table1.symbol and Table2.symbol share. Additionally not all between S through Z are returned.

Comment: Please provide database schema and sample data.

Comment: Who would downvote this? It's a new user's first question and it is well thought out, has tons of detail and supporting queries. Yes, more details are needed and we're asking for them in the comments. Sheesh.

Comment: Failed on the edit time limit- retry: I can manually verify that there are records before S that both Table1.symbol and Table2.symbol share. Additionally not all between S through Z are returned.  SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM Table.1 WHERE symbol BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z' --> (529 total, Query took 0.0037 sec) SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM Table2. WHERE symbol BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z' --> (1,438 Total, Query took 0.0034) I have also tried to see if there is a whitespace issue by using TRIM() to no avail. My expectation is for all symbols from Table1 that match Table2 to be output as Symbol/Industry.

Comment: Allow me a few moments to get better acquainted with posting here and I'll add additional information to clarify.

Comment: @Strawman Ok. When posting code blocks, use 4 spaces to indent. There's a `{}` toolbar editor button for that, or highlight and ctl-k.  If you tag me with @ in a comment, I'll be notified and have a look.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've done an edit with some links to associated images.  Additionally this is the third I could not post: Using a SELECT that only returns 192 records that starts at S through Z but only a small subset of what I am expecting

http://i61.tinypic.com/245lj0l.png

Comment: If the join doesn't succeed, the column values aren't equivalent (or aren't present) For giggles, try two things: First, perform the join with `TRIM()` on both sides:  `SELECT a.symbol, b.industry FROM alltimehigh a, symbolbase b WHERE TRIM(a.symbol) = TRIM(b.symbol)` and then try a left join, which will return nulls for the non-matching symbols. `SELECT a.symbol, b.industry FROM sumbolbase b LEFT JOIN alltimehigh a ON a.symbol = b.symbol`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Here is the response when I TRIM() http://i58.tinypic.com/kf4odl.png It returned a result of 30, but the image indicates 0 were returned.  There was also an error from phpMyAdmin: unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE x2, unknown table status: Comment  The second query timed out 5 times in a row so I stopped with that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for your assistance yesterday. I put in some elbow grease this morning and figured out how to check the last character ascii value to see if there was any junk.  It's evident a mixture of newline and carriage return is in one of my tables http://i57.tinypic.com/nxkej7.png so I need to spend some time figuring out how to strip that out and assure it gets stripped out before input.

Comment: @Strawman Good detective work- I figured it had to be something like that, as your queries are correct as written.